# How to get the pipeline configuration field 'Script Path' when executing the Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How can I get the content of the pipeline configuration field 'Script Path' in Jenkins from the Jenkinsfile (groovy)?

[image]

In this example: I want to get the string 'Apps/mq-logger/Jenkinsfile' when executing the Jenkinsfile itself.

Comment: can you explain your requirement a bit? Is your purpose to access this file for build or access it as a string?

Comment: @Sagar as I wrote: "I want to get the string..."
I need it to make some decisions in executing the pipeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a script path this way

```
def scriptPath = currentBuild.rawBuild.parent.definition.scriptPath
```

Note that you have to [approve](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) all these methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this string to be customizable during the build time, you can create a parameterized build as follows:

[image: parameterized build]

When you want to access this in your pipeline script by ${FileParameter} as follows:

```
pipeline {
 stages {
        stage('Perform verification') {
            steps {
                script {
                   echo "${FileParameter}"
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

If you don't want it to be customizable, then you can use global var. But if your target is to just get string form `Script Path`, then you have to use `@Vitalii Vitrenko` answer to use:

`def scriptPath = currentBuild.rawBuild.parent.definition.scriptPath`

and approve necessary permissions

Comment: I selected `@Vitalii Vitrenko` answer as he was first.
+1 for explaining how to access build parameters.